# Settings to use in Garageband for creating sounds for an iPhone application?

Tags: applications, iphone

I'm trying to create sounds to be used with a mobile app for iPhone. Is there a default setting in Garageband? Or is there another best practices way to get this accomplished? The sounds are spoken word.

I've tried different effects and settings (and no effects), but there is either a lot of background noise, or it is much too loud in the ad hoc version.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is more with your hardware if there's background noise. Also, you're being pretty general. We can't tell you what will work best for use in an iPhone app. You need to tell us more about the sounds, the effects you've tried, and the results you've gotten.

Comment: Are you asking how to record the sounds in the first place, or how to use existing files you have? What is "the ad hoc version"?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the internal mic of your mac or your iPhone you can not expect a good quality. You must use a real microphone like the one from [Apogee](http://apogeedigital.com/products/mic.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean using [garageband for creating ringtones](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1358), it's pretty straight forward and require no special settings. [From lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/#!334073/create-custom-iphone-ringtones-the-free-and-apple-way):

> Unfortunately Apple hasn't provided a similar tool for Windows users yet, and I imagine that won't happen for some time, if at all. But if you're a Mac owner, creating custom ringtones for your iPhone just became dead simple.

Comment: I think he's talking about App Development actually, which means... *choo choo* All aboard the Stack Overflow train. Then again, GarageBand is on-topic (obviously), there's also AVP.SE...

Comment: @Jason what does GarageBand has to do with app development?

Comment: All Windows users need to do is use something ( like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/windows)) to create an m4a, rename the file to m4r and import it into iTunes :D.

Comment: Maybe that should be an answer all on its own, @ephsmith